# Centralizers of group actions

Tags: gr.group-theory, ergodic-theory, oa.operator-algebras

Let a locally compact group $G$ act on a probability space $(X,\mu)$. Define the centralizer by $C(G)=\{\Delta\in Aut(X,\mu)\mid \Delta(gx)=g\Delta(x)\text{ almost everywhere}\}$. $Aut(X,\mu)$ denotes the set of $\mu$-preserving transformations of $X$. I am searching for actions $G\curvearrowright X$ such that the second centralizer $C(C(G))=G$.
In the following, i tacitly assume that all actions are faithful and i identify the acting group $G$ with the corresponding subgroup of $Aut(X,\mu)$.

Of course, for compact groups $G$ such actions exist: let $G$ act on itself (with normalized Haar measure) by left translation. The centralizer is the right translation action of $G$, and the second centralizer is again the left translation action of $G$.

I found a paper by Daniel Rudolph that asserts that the second centralizer of the Bernoulli action of $\mathbb{Z}$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Now I was wondering if the similar result holds for the Gaussian action associated to the left-regular representation of an arbitrary second countable locally compact group. Has this been studied?

Comment: sounds kind of like the bicommutant characterization of von Neumann algebras. 


Comment: Do you know if you have $C(C(C(G))) = C(G)$?  If so this might be a good way to find such actions.

Comment: Let me simply note that your condition cannot be satisfied very often - since centralizers are obviously closed it can only be satisfied if $G$ is closed, so for a countable $G$ the image of $G$ in $Aut(X,\mu)$ must be discrete. Hence, for some fixed countable $G$, a generic (in the sense of Baire category) $G$-action fails to satisfy your condition. However it often happens for abelian groups that the double commutant is the closure of $G$. Of course that does not say anything about the case of Gaussian actions and it seems reasonable to expect that they might behave like Bernoulli shifts... 

Comment: @agol: If we replace $Aut(X,\mu)$ by the infinite unitary group, we see that every group $G$ with this property must be the unitary group of some von Neumann algebra. Hence if it is locally compact, it is a direct product of finite unitary groups. (and hence compact)

Comment: @Jesse: For any group/algebra, the triple centralizer is again just the centralizer. In fact, i am searching for groups $G$ that are the centralizer of some group action, which is a equivalent to asking that $C(C(G))=G$.

Comment: @julien: You are of course right that we can not expect this property to hold generically, but it is an interesting question to ask if generically, the closure is the second centralizer.

Comment: @Steven: For generic Z-actions (say) the centralizer is the closure of the powers (that's a theorem of King) so the double centralizer is the closure. This extends to most abelian groups (all those that contain an element of infinite order, for instance). For a generic action of the free group on 2 generators the corresponding copy of the free group is dense in $Aut(X,\mu)$, so the centralizer is trivial and the double centralizer is again the closure in this case. Maybe this is true for all countable groups...